# Python Filter Dataframe with an unknown list of values with Kwargs

Tags: python, pandas, args

Im new to coding but I wanted to see if there was a way to filter a dataframe with an unknown number of values. What I have so far

```
df[(df['column'].astype(str)=='one')|(df['column'].astype(str)=='two')|(df['column'].astype(str)=='three')]
```

This filters a dataframe just fine but I have an unknown number of values. What I wanted would be something like:

```
x=['one','two','three']
y=['one','two','three','four']
z=['one','two','three','four','five']

for arg in *args:
     df=df[(df['column'].astype(str)==arg )]
```

But this does not seem to work. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
>>> df[df['column'].isin(x)]  # or y or z
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the answer and Ill Accept it in 10mins when Stack allows me to